# Sink Trap Leak After Faucet Replacement

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, p-trap

[image]I just replaced my bathroom sink and added new faucet which came with drain kit. I can’t get the circled connector to stop leaking and it really feels like the new drain pipe is just too small to have a good seal. Using the washer on the pipe and then hand tightening but can’t get water to stop bubbling out the top. Thoughts?

Added 2/26 - pic showing gap between p trap and drain tailpiece. Seems like it might need some overlap instead of just different gasket. This is the only config possible with existing equipment.

[image: p trap pic]

Comment: Also make sure the compression ring on each end of the P is facing the right direction.  The tapered end typically faces the male fitting, the flat end faces the female fitting. https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61wCfspvF5L._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg

Comment: Can you easily move the sink tailpiece inside the trap bend? They should fit together tightly enough that you can't easily slide them.

Comment: It didn’t occur to me that the tapered end of the gasket would face the sink instead of female end of p trap like the other fitting. Can try that but to answer other question, there is play between tailpiece and trap bend so maybe I need an intermediate piece to tighten these up?

Comment: @KathyJ the flat wide end of the gasket should contact the inside face of the nut. The "cone" face of the gasket should contact the inside/end of the outer-threaded end of pipe.

Comment: I usually tighten the nut hand-tight plus an extra 1/2 turn or so.

Comment: Yes - that’s the direction I put it on going to try the smaller washer and will really tighten. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Re: "pic showing gap between p trap and drain tailpiece." If you mean the tailpiece does not actually extend through the yellow gasket and into the P trap pipe opening, then yes it is too short. You might be able to cut off the last 6 inches or so and instead insert a longer 8 or 10 inch tube using slipjoint connections on both its ends (search "slip joint sink drain extension tube").

Comment: Armand, thank you!

Comment: I did get a 1 1/4 P Tube extender and cut it down. That did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Bath drain tailpieces are either 1 1/2 or 1 1/4 inches. Your sink tail piece looks to be the smaller option.

Ptraps usually come with 2 sealing washers that fit either size tailpiece.

You probably have the 1 1/2 washer and need a 1 1/4 washer.  They are regularly available where plumbing parts are sold.

Comment: Might possibly have been one in the bag with the drain, even!

Comment: There are three kinds of washer for this kind of joint:  1-1/4, 1-1/2, and an adapting one, which is what you need, to connect a 1-1/4 tail piece to a 1-1/2 trap.  The trap should have come with a 1-1/2 and an adapting one.   The adapting one is thicker than the other two, for (hopefully) obvious reasons.  If you threw it out, it's easy to buy a new one.   Note these are all V-shaped teflon washers, not the flat rubber washers that are used in other kinds of joint.

Comment: I have the old washers, new ones and even bought more but yes, only the v shape should be needed over drain tailpiece. I think even with those, these pieces aren’t fitting together tightly enough.

Comment: Will measure all of these today to see if any are the 1 1/4 inch - betting all are 1 1/2. Thanks and will try that!

Comment: To be precise, you are measuring the diameter of the inside...the "hole". The outside diameters will all be the same...or extremally close to the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It does look too small to properly seal.

**Quick temporary fix** would be to get some plumber putty.

Then roll if in you hands till reassembles a snake with thickness of a pencil.

Put the plumber putty snake around the upper pipe then tighten it it the nut.

Eventually go to store and find a proper o-ring to use or even better take out the u-shape bring it to the store and find one the has smaller end.

Comment: I'd put a bucket under it before I'd goof around with putty. Putty isn't for sealing pipes. It's for keeping dirt out of cracks.

Comment: There are many uses for products that are meant for some other specific purpose.  I wouldn't criticize using plumbers putty for a short term fix until the proper needed materials can be obtained.  I have used a giant wad of plumber putty on a broken drain under a neighbors sink.  I placed a bucket too. I was getting the needed components the next day.  To my surprise, his wife washed all the dishes from a party and there was not a drop in the bucket ( no pun)  So plumbers putty can seal even a substantial leak...just not suited for permeant solutions.

Comment: Yeah - I would love to duct tape and putty the crap out of it but it seems I could maybe get to these freakin pipes fitting and my pan will remind me to keep trying!